# jQuery Global variables are not accessible by functions

Tags: jquery, global-variables

I have a snippet of code, to calculate the width of some child items and instead of declaring the parentWidth and other variables in EVERY function.. I am trying to create Global variables to be re-used.. but, its not working.

Here is a portion of my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

parentWidth = $(this).parent().width();     // parent width in pixels
margin = parentWidth/100;               // pixel equivalent of a 1% margin
border = 6;                 // 6px total border for each input field 


    $(".element.twoinone input").each(function() {
        $(this).css( 'width',
            (((parentWidth - (margin * 2)) - (border * 2))  / 2)
            + 'px' );
    });
});
```

The parentWidth, margin and border variables are NOT accessed by the 'each' function (which I have multiple of). I've tried using live(), livequery(),.. etc.. but, no dice. I know its probably something simple that this noob is overlooking.. so any help is greatly appreciated !!
Thanks!
Also, if you have any input on calculating width percentages based on a parent containers width and accounting for each elements border, margin and qty,.. I'm all ears :D

**UPDATE**
Isn't this:
 $(document).ready(function(){

```
parentWidth = $(this).parent().width();     

    $(".element.twoinone input").each(function() {
        $(this).css( 'width',
            (((parentWidth - (margin * 2)) - (border * 2))  / 2)
            + 'px' );
    });
});
```

The same as this:

$(document).ready(function(){

```
    $(".element.twoinone input").each(function() {
        $(this).css( 'width',
            (((     $(this).parent().width()     - (margin * 2)) - (border * 2))  / 2)
            + 'px' );
    });
});
```

Comment: What are you *expecting* `this` to be when calculating the parent width?

Comment: I am expecting 'this' to be the element I am using the variable IN.. so, when using parentWidth inside $(".element.twoinone input"), I am wanting 'this' == $(".element.twoinone input")

Comment: Isn't this:

parentWidth = $(this).parent().width();
$(".element.twoinone input").each(function() {
    $(this).css( 'width',
     (((parentWidth - (margin * 2)) - (border * 2))  / 2)
      + 'px' );
});



the same as this:

$(".element.twoinone input").each(function() {
    $(this).css( 'width',
     (((    $(this).parent().width()    - (margin * 2)) - (border * 2))  / 2)
      + 'px' );
});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're declaring this:

```
parentWidth = $(this).parent().width();
```

You're not getting the width *of the parent of that element* (the `<input>`), it's using `document` for `this`, since that's the context you're in.  You need to get the width inside the function, either inside each or as a plugin, but not "globally" like this.

Comment: ah.. gotcha.. so, there is not way to make a variable using 'this' and when using that variable inside of a function, have 'this' == the element we are in at that time ???

Comment: @revive -  You could make `$(this).parentWidth()` a function shortcut if you wanted, like this:  `$.fn.parentWidth = function { return this.parent().width(); };`  But I'm not sure that buys you much, so up to you :)

Comment: haven't tried this yet.. I just want to be able to access the variables in all the functions within that docready... will this achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

`parentWidth` is not a global variable it exist in the `document.ready` function but its not a global variable for any function.

Except if you declared this variable before the `document.ready`:
Something like this:

```
var parentWidth;
$(document).ready(function(){
parentWidth = $(this).parent().width();
....
```

The same goes with the other 2 variables.

Comment: This isn't the problem, the variables are accessible, scoping isn't an issue here :)

Comment: I tried both - adding it as a Var before the docready.. and also changing the name of parentWidth to elementWidth.. nothing changed and not widths were calculated.. they DO calculate properly when I include the variables in each of the functions.. but, I am hoping to learn a way to re-use code better than that LOL :D Thanks!

Comment: yes i got it, @Nick Craver is taking you to the right solution.

Comment: see clarification in orig post

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the variables outside the `$(document).ready()`